# Using Cells to change max/min on existing Chart

Tags: excel, vba

Using cells to Change x/y Min/Max on an existing Chart

I have tried a few websites that give a generic code but none of them work for me

```
Private Sub ChartDimension()
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    .MinimumScale = .Range("B72").Value
    .MaximumScale = .Range("B71").Value
    End With
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
    .MinimumScale = .Range("B70").Value
    .MaximumScale = .Range("B69").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

"Object Variable or With Block variable not set" Is the error message i am receiving

Comment: Guess you'll need sheet references in front of those ranges.

Comment: Still doesn't work and i still have the same error message

Comment: i added `.MinimumScale = Sheets("ORI -PERFO-SONIC-NOZZLES").Range("B72").Value` to all min/max rows, still the same error code

Comment: Works for me on a scatter chart. Do the cells all definitely contain numbers.

Comment: OK, glad it works. You're probably better off not relying on active chart as it has to be selected for the code to work. Instead set a reference to the chart object.

Comment: It says its buged and highlights the forst line "With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)"

Comment: Sorry but it doesnt work due to it being connected to a button, how would i dimension the chart then say with chart

Comment: You can use its name or index.

Comment: I used ```With Charts(1).Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)``` Still giving me that error

Comment: I've posted some code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference a chart using its name or index, viz. If you are creating the chart in code too you can build that in.

```
Private Sub ChartDimension()

With ActiveSheet
    With .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary) 'or .ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    .MinimumScale = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c1").Value
    .MaximumScale = Range("c2").Value
    End With
    With .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
    .MinimumScale = Range("c3").Value
    .MaximumScale = Range("c4").Value
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set-up all your `Worksheet` and `ChartObjects`, that will create a shorter and clearer piece of code:

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ChartDimension()

Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim Sht As Worksheet

' set the Worksheet object
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORI -PERFO-SONIC-NOZZLES")

' set the Chart-Object
Set ChtObj = Sht.ChartObjects("Chart 1")  ' rename "Chart 1" to your chart's name
With ChtObj
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = Sht.Range("B72").Value
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = Sht.Range("B71").Value

    .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = Sht.Range("B70").Value
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = Sht.Range("B69").Value
End With

End Sub
```